# How to make jquery pop up box responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

i have jQuery pop up responsive , it works but when i change the size of the page , it stays on the right side . ( jQuery 1.3.2 & jQuery UI 1.7.1 is used )

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

```
.ui-widget-header {
    background: white;
    border: 0px;
    color:black;
}

#ui-dialog-title-dialog {
background-color: black;

}

.ui-widget-overlay {
    background: none repeat-x scroll 0 0 black;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

and function side is here :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $dialog = $('<div stye="float:left;" width:auto;"></div>')
         .html('<p>Lütfen kişi veya kişileri hedef alan haberler yazmayınız.</p><p>Gerçeği yansıtmayan haberler paylaşmayınız. </p><ul><li>Eklediğiniz haberler Admin tarafından onaylandıktan sonra yayınlanacaktır.</li><li>Boyabat.net sitesini kullandığınız için teşekkür ederiz...</li></ul><table style="margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto;"></table>')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            resizable: true,
            draggable: true,
            width: 'auto', // overcomes width:'auto' and maxWidth bug
            height: 300,
            maxWidth: 600,
            modal: true,
            title: 'Haber Ekleme Kuralları'
        });

    });
```

it works fine but when i run my responsive template and  changeit is size to iphone , it is not appera in the screen. I just need a solution on that .

Comment: *sidenote:* why use jQuery 1.3.2 ? Such an old version?

Comment: it is an example..if i use latest version, the problem  goes away ?

Comment: You can try. Also, you don't need to post the `<script>` tag here.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is mostly happen by CSS file, You can adjust the @media file 
with responsive size for example for S3 380 Widh 
you set and enjoy this feature.